# Rig is making lips clip and arms move the eyes

Tags: rigging

Eyes are moved by the arms and when he crouched the lips go inside his body. I couldn’t add that picture though because I can’t for some reason have two pictures.[image]

Comment: you can easily paste two pictures by just drag'n drop or paste them in the question. Please do not make photos of your screen because they are hard to read. Please use screenshots. Thanks. And providing your blend file would be a big help, because you didn't describe anything you made and didn't show us any useful information.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Rather than take photos of your monitor post actual screenshots instead, see [How to take a screenshot](https://www.take-a-screenshot.org). Photos are harder to read, because we have to guess if we are looking at a external interference like reflections or smudges or Moiré patterns, hardware issues such as a malfunctioning display or connection, a software level bug or driver malfunction, or an or actual artifact or issue with the model itself.

Answer (score 1):

These parts are not assigned to the good vertex groups, so they are going to be moved by the wrong bones.

In *Edit* mode select the eye and the lips and in the *Object Data panel > Vertex Groups*, remove these parts from all groups:

[image]

Then select the eye, select the vertex group it is supposed to be part of, and press on the *Assign* button. Same for the lips:

[image]